# What would be a better way to write this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
def useable?
    if !self.value.nil? and self.active and !self.used?
        unless self.starts.nil?
            if self.starts > Time.now
                return false
            end
        end
        unless self.ends.nil?
            if self.ends < Time.now
                return false
            end
        end
        return true
    end
    return false
end
```

I'm pretty new to Ruby and Rails and have a feeling this block of code could be written much better, but for the life of me am unable to come up with something that works.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review

Comment: Apologies @MikeCampbell, I will look into this now, didn't know it exists and looks like a very helpful resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is more fit for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), but here you go.

```
def useable?
  return false unless value && active && !used?
  return false if starts && starts > Time.now
  return false if ends && ends < Time.now

  true
end
```

Tip: you don't need to use `self` with reader methods.

Comment: With the minor modification of '!used?', it works! Thanks for the help, I will look into CodeReview now. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
def useable?
  return false if value.nil? or active.! or used?
  return starts <= Time.now unless starts.nil?
  return ends >= Time.now unless ends.nil?
  return true
end
```

Comment: Which part? Are you claiming against `.!`? The code is faithful to what the OP had.

Comment: Yes, the `.!`. I don't see how it came from the original code.

Comment: In the  original code, it goes to the bottom `return false` if it misses `if ... self.active ...`.

Comment: Sorry, don't mind my last comment (now deleted) :)

Comment: Ah, it's the negation (and actually valid code). That's the weirdest thing I have seen someone write in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe this is you want.

```
def useable?
    if starts and ends and value and active and used
        return false if starts > Time.now or ends < Time.now
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end
```

some advises:

(1)    !self.value.nil?  ==equal to ==>  self.value

(2)  reduce code lines

```
if self.ends < Time.now
   return false
end
```

equal to :

```
return false if self.ends < Time.now
```

Comment: His code will not always return false.